# How to wait for setOutputData WorkManager

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem where WorkManager just continues to the next line after an enqueue of a task and doesn't wait till the outputData is set, how would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who see this, I fixed this by using observeForever, which negates the requirement of having to implement a LifecycleOwner.